# Why can't I convert curves to mesh?

Tags: mesh, hair, bezier-curves

So I made a model (of hair) using entirely bezier curves and a circle (using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk) tutorial) and plan to import it into Secondlife. All's fine and well, but I noticed I might need to use the decimate modifier to get rid of some of those extra vertices and transport it.

However, you can't do that with curves, so I looked up how to convert curves into mesh and, low and behold, somehow none of the commands work. When I looked up 'covert' in the Object menu, both of the options (Mesh to Curve and Curve to Mesh respectively) are greyed out and I can't click 'em.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of everything selected!
[image]

I've tried with and without the bevel taper objects selected, with and without the entire head of hair grouped together. When I select a few chunks of hair at a time, it lets me convert.

What's happened?
Thank you!

Comment: are you using the hair modifier or just creating curves that represent "hair"?

Comment: What object is active when you try using Convert commands? Could you show some screenshots of the object itself?

Comment: @rob Thank you for your comment! They are just curves that represent hair.

Comment: @MrZak I tried to convert when just selecting one of the curves, and it worked, but when I've got them all selected it won't. I'll add a screen to my original post now!

Comment: I don't see any active object on the screenshot. Active object is outlined with light orange. Multiple curves can be converted to meshes at once just fine, select them and select one curve last, then head over to Object > Convert. Lastly upload screenshots directly here please, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 5):

I ended up figuring it out.
Turns out, you have to individually select every single curve for this to work - not select them altogether, or as a group. Everything's working just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

> I ended up figuring it out. Turns out, you have to individually select every single curve for this to work - not select them altogether, or as a group. Everything's working just fine now.

The reason you must select them one at a time is because the operation is only performed on the active object. Blender only activates the most recent of any number of objects which have been selected. If only selecting a single object, it is  always also the active object. But when selecting multiple objects, only one of them is ever active. And that is the one targeted by the operation. To prove this. do a test and select a series of objects. They will be highlighted orange, but the active one will be highlighted yellow. As you continue to add more objects to the selection, the active one always changes to the most recent one selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make everyone you selected active. After you selected them you have to go and right click with the mouse on one of the selected objects on the scene collection tab (the one on the right) and click select, now you can convert them all together. Hope it helps :)